# Url routing and web.config of nested folder

Tags: asp.net, web-config, url-routing

I'm using URL routing (with WebForms) in the following format:

```
http://host/project/{projectid}/{pageName}
```

Another option is that the user is refering to a subapplication:

```
http://host/project/{projectid}/{application}/{pageName}
```

The subapplication isn't a new web application, simply a virtual directory.
My subapplication does have a web.config, which contains some specific appsettings/connstrings.

Everything works fine without the URL routing.

However when I request an URL in the routed form the web.config of the subapplication isn't processed and I get a null reference on all of the appsettings/connstrings (through ConfigurationManager).

Here's the code in my custom handler:

```
string path = String.Format(_pagesFormat, application, pageName);   
return (IHttpHandler) BuildManager.CreateInstanceFromVirtualPath(path, typeof(Page));
```

It works if I would change my route to `http://host/{application}/{projectid}/{pageName}`
This probably triggers IIS to load the web.config of the virtual directory as well.

Can I somehow force the settings of the nested web.config to be loaded?

**EDIT:**
This person has a similar problem:
http://forums.asp.net/p/1452479/3317775.aspx

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For some reason the system.web tag and a few other tags **are** being processed by the
web.config (that resides in the virtual directory).

I've decided to put my application settings and connection string settings into two separate files in the root:

- web.config in the root (IS, compilation, handler configuration)
- web.AppSettings.config in the root
- web.Connections.config in the root
- web.config per virtual directory (user control, masterpage configuration)